# SVM manual implementation to find missing values

Tags: svm, data-imputation

How SVM algorithm can be used to impute the missing data in a dataset. I need a manual implementation of the SVM algorithm to find missing values with an example.

Answer (score 0):

SVMs do not specifically treat missing feature values. LibSVM and SVMlight, the most popular implementations of SVMs, utilise sparse representation of data. So for both missing data is treated the same as 0-valued features.